# telephone links from Android WebView opening error URL instead of phone dialer

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 to build a simple webview app. The webview is navigating through the content with no problem. The issue is that the telephone links within the webview pages are opening as URLs instead of launching the phone's dialer. I've tried at least 8 different code snippets that I've found on SO to resolve this but nothing has worked.

Here is the MAINACTIVITY.JAVA: 
    package com.appname;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView appWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
appWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = appWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
appWebView.loadUrl("http://website.com”);
appWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
}else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
view.loadUrl(url);
}
return true;
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if(appWebView.canGoBack()) {
appWebView.goBack();
} else {
super.onBackPressed();
}

}

}
```

...and all the phone links are formatted as:

```
<a href="tel:1234567890" launch-external="true">
```

I'm pretty new to this and can't seem to get it ironed out. Thanks in advance for your help.